# What the difference between saving a dataset as a CSV file compared to saving as a RDA file?

Tags: r, csv, rda

Just out of curiosity, I was wondering if there were any advantages (e.g., space efficiency etc) to saving a dataset as a RDA file compared to using a CSV?

Comment: A CSV will be smaller, and portable. An RDA will be bigger, not portable, but faster to load.

Comment: Why don't you save the file both ways and judge for yourself?

Comment: @nograpes RDA need not be bigger, it's often smaller in size than a CSV.

Answer (score 4):

Both:

```
m<-matrix(1:1000000,1000)

> system.time(write.csv(m,file="csv.csv"))
user  system elapsed 
1.33    0.08    1.42 
# size 6,741KB

> system.time(save(m,file="m.RData"))
user  system elapsed 
0.84    0.03    0.87
# size 2,079KB
```